# Prevent SSH client passing TERM environment variable to server?

Tags: ssh, terminal, environment-variables, gnome-terminal

I'm currently using [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org) 18 [gnome-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal), then started [`tmux`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tmux) multiplexer in it. After I connected to a [CentOS](http://centos.org) 5 server via `ssh` command, I find:

- `ls` result has no color
- `tmux`, `screen`, `hexedit`, `htop` all failed to start with error message like:

  > open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: screen-256color

It seems that `ssh` passes the $TERM environment variable to the server, but I can't find it in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file of Fedora 18.

Although I can manually change the $TERM variable on the server, each time I connect, it happens again. So how to prevent it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$TERM` is to tell applications what terminal they're talking to so they know how to talk to it.

Change it to a value supported by the remote host and that matches as closely as possible your terminal (`screen`).

Most Linux systems should at least have a `screen` terminfo entry. If not, `screen` implements a superset of `vt100` and `vt100` is universal. So:

```
TERM=screen ssh host
```

or

```
TERM=vt100 ssh host
```

If you do need the 256 color support, you could try `xterm-256color` which should be close enough (`screen` supports 256 colors the same way `xterm` does) and tell applications your terminal application supports 256 colors and tell them how to use them.

Or you can install the terminfo entry on the remote host.

```
infocmp -x | ssh -t root@remote-host '
  cat > "$TERM.info" && tic -x "$TERM.info"'
```

Comment: good to know `infocmp` and `tic`, once compiled, no need to temporarily change `$TERM` again. by the way, i just copied (rsync) `/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color` from Fedora 18 to CentOS, it seems works ok (`rsync -tv /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color root@the_host:/usr/share/terminfo/s`).

Comment: forgot to mentioned, i ran `tmux` in gnome-terminal of Fedora 18, `tmux` changed `$TERM` value to `screen-256color` from `xterm-256color`.

Comment: btw, can ssh works in this way: get the terminfo which host/server supported (not pushed into), then pickup one the client terminal can support?

Comment: I found it amusing that this infocmp piped through ssh thing left a file called dumb.info in my home dir.

Comment: `infocmp | ssh -t root@remote-host 'cat > "$TERM.info" && tic "$TERM.info"'` can be shortened to `infocmp | ssh root@remote-host "tic -"`. This works because when you have a pipe it can be accessed as a file by using - and luckily pipes work across SSH.

Comment: I copy the terminfo file from `/usr/share/terminfo` to the same place on the remote host. Is there any reason why using `infocmp` and `tic` would be preferable?

Comment: @starfry, I can't give you any guarantee that the binary format of the `tic` (terminfo compiler) generated files will be the same from one system to the next or that their location will be the same. `tic` may also make sure the permissions are correct or create intermediary directories where needed.

Comment: The original command gave me `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` error, while the shortened version actually worked for me. Alacritty works on ssh now =)

Answer (score 21):

In my case I simply added an alias to my `.zshrc` (`.bashrc` if using bash) on my local desktop:

```
alias ssh='TERM=xterm ssh'
```

If you already use an alias, adjust it to include the Environment assignment.

Comment: This solution is less desirable as it dumbs down the terminal support on the remote host, while uploading the terminal defintiions to your home directory on the server allows full terminal support in the remote connection.

Comment: Ended up being the winner for me - I'm using kitty terminal, and none of the machines I SSH into have any support for that, so setting the TERM value back to a common base value is probably the best option in almost all cases

Answer (score 6):

Changing `$TERM` might work, but I don't suggest this, it's only a workaround instead of a solution.

When I encounter this problem on my systems, I fix it by installing support for the most common terminal types to the remote system:

- `yum install ncurses-base` for `screen-256color` on CentOS
- `yum install ncurses-term` for `screen-256color-bce` on CentOS
- `apt install ncurses-base` for both `screen-256color` and `screen-256color-bce` on Debian, Ubuntu and Mint

The ncurses-related packages also provide support for a lot of other terminals, and they are also available on all other large distributions. (But for my use-case and your question this should be enough info)

Comment: This may be the best answer, assuming desire/permission to install packages remotely.

Comment: Besides that you might not have permission to install packages remotely, such a package might not be available. For example Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 are still active LTS lines, but the terminal info for the `alacritty` terminal is not packaged until 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to end up with full terminal support during SSH sessions. To achieve this, upload your `terminfo` files to your home directory on the remote server.

Locally: Check your working TERM value:

```
 echo $TERM
```

In the following examples `alacritty` is used.  Next, find local the `terminfo` files for your  terminal:

```
 locate alacritty | grep terminfo
```

I found results under `/usr/share/terminfo`.  Finally, upload the files to `~/.terminfo on the remote host.

```
 # On the remote host
 mkdir -p ~/.terminfo/a

 # Locally
 scp /usr/share/terminfo/a/alacritty* remotehost:.terminfo/a/
```

The terminfo format is a compiled format so simply copying the files may not work. If it doesn't work and `infocmp` and `tic` are available locally and remotely, you can use this method instead:

```
 infocmp -x | ssh -t root@remote-host 'cat > "$TERM.info" && tic -x "$TERM.info"'
```

Comment: This is a really cool solution. The only negative is that it involves a bit of effort for a server you might only connect to once. For the other usecases it's robust and less guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

See man ssh_config:

```
 SendEnv
         Specifies what variables from the local environ(7) should be sent
         to the server.  Note that environment passing is only supported
         for protocol 2.  The server must also support it, and the server
         must be configured to accept these environment variables.  Refer
         to AcceptEnv in sshd_config(5) for how to configure the server.
         Variables are specified by name, which may contain wildcard char‐
         acters.  Multiple environment variables may be separated by
         whitespace or spread across multiple SendEnv directives. The
         default is not to send any environment variables.
```

and man sshd_config:

```
 AcceptEnv
         Specifies what environment variables sent by the client will be
         copied into the session's environ(7).  See SendEnv in
         ssh_config(5) for how to configure the client.  Note that envi-
         ronment passing is only supported for protocol 2.  Variables are
         specified by name, which may contain the wildcard characters `*'
         and `?'.  Multiple environment variables may be separated by
         whitespace or spread across multiple AcceptEnv directives.  Be
         warned that some environment variables could be used to bypass
         restricted user environments.  For this reason, care should be
         taken in the use of this directive.  The default is not to accept
         any environment variables.
```

According to that, the default should be not to send any variables, but TERM seems to be special. It is send anyway.

Therefore you can either change TERM when calling ssh (like `TERM=xterm ssh ...`), change it after login (like in `.bash_profile`), or define the unknown TERM type on server side (assuming you have root access there). See other answer for details.

Comment: Not setting `$TERM` will not really be any better than setting it to an unsupported value though.

Comment: The literal question was, how to prevent sending TERM. - Answer: You cannot. - What he should do is setting it to a suitable value, yes.

Comment: change `$TERM` temporarily may be a workaround, but i need to do it each time. by the way, it seems that both CentOS 5 and Fedora 18 Accept*Env* all locale environment variables (`LANG`, `LC_*`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my `.bashrc` on the remote host:

```
# 256-color mode not supported on this host
if echo $TERM | grep -q -- '-256color'; then
    echo -e '\n\n256-color mode not supported on this host.  Reverting TERM...\n'
    export TERM=`echo -n $TERM | sed 's/-256color//'`
fi
```

That way, both `xterm-256color` and `screen-265color` are handled properly.  Also, I have it output the note so that if the server gets upgraded later and supports 256 colors, I won't end up banging my head against the wall wondering why my TERM variable gets changed when SSHing.

Comment: Or, don't start a subshell and another process: `export TERM=${TERM%%-256color}`

Comment: If you are willing to use a solution that involves modifying files on every remote server you ssh into, you could instead install the desired terminal support files in `~/.terminfo` on all the remote hosts.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is add a function to my shell (`.zshrc` in my case) :

```
ssht() {
    ssh $1 'mkdir -p  ~/.terminfo/'${TERM:0:1} && scp /usr/share/terminfo/${TERM:0:1}/$TERM $1:~/.terminfo/${TERM:0:1}/$TERM && ssh $1
}
```

Then I `ssht myserver` or (`ssht user@server.ext` if I did't put the user/host in `.ssh/config`) the first time I connect to a server.

It copies my current terminfo file to the server user's home `.terminfo` directory (after having created the directory) and then connects me.